# Ingesting to ElasticSearch a json file using curl

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl

I have the following error when I try to ingest a json file

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}
```

My file is like this:

```
   [{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
},
{
"name":"John2",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford2", "BMW2", "Fiat2" ]
}]
```

It works if I only have one record not more than one.
The curl command is like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/cars/doc/1 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @cars.json
```